# Handling "Open With" menu on Appium Android?

Tags: java, android, saucelabs, appium-android

I've written an Appium test for opening up the phone dialer and confirming that the correct phone number was passed to the dialer.  This works great when run against an emulator.  However, I'm trying to run it against a real device as well.  The problem here is my test fails because after going to open the dialer, the user is presented with the "Open With" menu where they can choose what application to open it with.

Is there a way in Appium to handle this?  Either have it auto accept one like with permissions or handle it manually?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webdriverIO then you try to find the partial text in Open With menu.

For example, my requirement was to open the browser from mobile app via Open With menu. I took the following approach.

```
const selector = 'new UiSelector().textContains("Browser").className("android.widget.TextView")';
browser.click(`android=${selector}`);
```